# Listening for a file being clicked to - Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am trying to write an Eclipse plugin where one of the features requires **listening for when the user switches to another file in the editor via clicking**.

For example, consider the screenshot below.

[image]

I want to know how to listen for when the user switching over to `FakeClass.java` via double-clicking on it in the Project Explorer or clicking on the tab in the editor. Furthermore, I would like to get information about the element that was clicked. **Note that I am asking specifically about changing a file through the two means I asked above**.

I am a beginner with Plugin development. It would be helpful to explain with that in mind. Thanks.

Comment: It isn't usual to want to know the reason an editor was opened so I'm not sure there is a straightforward way to find this out. Also what about 'Package Explorer' or 'Resource Navigator' - there are several views which a user might use - personally I never use Project Explorer.

Comment: Is it at least possible to detect which tab was clicked? Also, I am confused by what you mean about 'Package Explorer' or 'Resource Navigator'.

Comment: You can use an `IPartListener` to be told about parts (editor or view) being activated but you aren't told why it is being activated. 'Project Explorer' is just one of the views people can use to see their projects and files, there are alternatives such a 'Package Explorer'

Comment: Thank you. I guess this means I might want to try doing something that allows me to guess that a file has opened via clicking. I plan on using a `Listener` for `SWT.MouseUp` events and then check whether or not a file was opened via MouseUp event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `IPartListener` to listen for changes to parts including a part being activated:

```java
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

page.addPartListener(listener);
```

The `partActivated` method of the listener is probably what you want:

```java
@Override
public void partActivated(final IWorkbenchPart part)
{
  if (part instanceof IEditorPart) {
    IEditorPart editor = (IEditorPart)part;

    IEditorInput input = editor.getEditorInput();

    IFile file = input.getAdapter(IFile.class);
    if (file != null) {
       // TODO handle file
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know of a way to tell why the part was activated.

Comment: I am not sure what the case is but `file` appears to be null.

Comment: Sorry, missed out a bit of code - the file is in the `IEditorInput` - see updated answer.